# Button.Flyout property not available

Tags: xaml, flyout

I'm developing a wp app, IDE: VisualStudio 2013

when I try to use flyout in button. button.flyout is not listed out in XAML page

Ref:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn308515.aspx

```
     <Button Name="btnFly" Content="img">
        <Button.Flyout>

        </Button.Flyout>
    </Button>
```

Button.Flyout is not listed when I put.[dot]

Comment: This question needs at least a snippet of the non-working code if not a cut-down full example.

Comment: You need to edit your original post and add the code, not put it into a comment.  Please try to format the code properly.

Answer (score 0):

You have create Windows Phone 8.1 app that uses Windows Runtime not the Silverlight.